# Laravel, Pass multiple input values to controller from url and form

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass many inputs value to controller so I want to compare them with values in database, also I want to send thease value in the url, Im new to laravel so please help me

**route:**

```
Route::get('/store/caterer_search/{filter?}','HomeController@StoreSearch');
```

**form:**

```
<form class="order-box__input-wrapper" name="form_mainpage" id="form_mainpage" action="/store/caterer_search/" method="get"  enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="order-box__input">
        <div class="address-bar-input">

            <input type="text" aria-label="Enter address" id="autocomplete" onFocus="geolocate()" name="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your delivery address" data-role="address-field" onClick="this.select();">
            <input class="field" id="city" hidden=""></input>

            <input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" hidden=""></input>
            <input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" hidden="" ></input>
            <input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" name="locality" ></input>
            <input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"name="administrative_area_level_1"></input>

            <input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" name="postal_code" ></input>

            <input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" hidden=""></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <i class="icon icon-location"></i>
    <button type="submit" id="homesearchbtn" class="btn btn--primary order-box__submit" aria-label="Search for caterers" disabled="">Search</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

**controller:**

```
public function StoreSearch($autocomplete,$locality,$administrative_area_level_1,$postal_code)
{
    $stores = Storeinfo::getStoreByLocation($autocomplete);

    return view('hotels.archive',compact('hotel','country','city','star'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes.

- If you use the "GET" method, you can not use the `multipart/form-data` value for the enctype attribute. In this case you do not have inputs file fields so you can remove the attribute
- These inputs: `<input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" hidden=""></input>` are useless. They do not have a type and they will not be sent to the form. If they are hidden fields, you must add `type="hidden"` to them

You defined the route in this way:

```
Route::get('/store/caterer_search/{filter?}','HomeController@StoreSearch');
```

So the controller should be like this:

```
public function StoreSearch(Request $request, $filter = null) {
    //
    $autocomplete = $request->input("autocomplete", "");

    $stores = Storeinfo::getStoreByLocation($autocomplete);

    return view('hotels.archive',compact('hotel','country','city','star'));
}
```

As you can see the `filter` parameter of the route is pretty useless, I do not know why you added to the route.

Inside the controller function, you get input parameters with this code:

```
$request->input("name_of_the_field", "default_value");
```

Comment: Im getting error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: even me, I dont use foreach but dont know why Im getting this error

Comment: your solution doesn't work with me, the url is very complex and I dont know how to fix it, I want to do like ezcater.com when using search its redirect to url something like this: https://www.ezcater.com/store/caterer_search/99650224

Comment: the url is not important. Try to explain what are you trying to do, what you tried and why my code does not work

Comment: all great but I want to change the url to be more short hope you can help me in this

Comment: you mean you wanna crypt the string after "caterer_search"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196271/discussion-between-ash-and-giacomo-m).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `Form::open()` ? It may works..

```
Form::open(['route' => ['HomeController.StoreSearch', $autocomplete, $some_other_parameter]])
```